# How to use one database for two deffrent domain using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cross-domain

I have a project and its working fine on a domain I want to upload that project in different domain. 
Example: my domain is xyz.com and I want to upload same files in abc.com domain, on abc.com I want to connect a database from xyz.com it is possible..?

In simple word's I want to upload my one project in two different domains using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. CodeIgniter uses SQL so figure out how to share the database between the two servers.

Comment: please explain from which file..?

Comment: You need to configure the database too allow connections from the other domain, how that is done depends on what database server you're using and any potential network snares (such as firewalls). Then on the other domain configure CodeIgniter to use that database. Without knowing specifics I can't say more.

Comment: If you're using a webhost and you don't have access to the webserver/database server directly (ie. you can only upload files with ftp) then you can't do this.